# How can I DROP nopCommerce plugin tables dynamically?

Tags: c#, t-sql, plugins, nopcommerce

> I recently developed a fairly large plugin that saw a lot of changes
>   throughout. I asked myself this question after having to manually drop
>   tables I forgot to include in the `Uninstall()` method.

I am building a nopCommerce plugin, and I want to make my `PluginNameObjectContext.Uninstall()` method more flexible.

I followed [Alex Wolf's tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=nopcommerce-plugin-development&author=alex-wolf&name=nopcommerce-plugin-development-m3&clip=1&mode=live)*, and it currently looks like:

```
this.DropPluginTable("firstTable");
this.DropPluginTable("secondTable");
....
this.DropPluginTable("nthTable");
```

There are a lot of places that a change to the plugin's data access layer need to be reflected in the code. I keep forgetting to update this method when I add or remove classes in the Plugin's domain, which leads to errors and then some cleanup.

How can I make this method more dynamic, and reduce the maintenance burden throughout development burden?

---

* The video series is for Nop 3.5, so is technically 0.2 versions behind the current, but it is **absolutely priceless** if you are new to nopCommerce development. His [blog](http://alexwolfthoughts.com/) has some very helpful posts, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the `Convention over Configuration` principle championed by MVC, and NopCommerce, we can take advantage of consistent naming.

Adhere to naming conventions when configuring Data Access, specifically your `EntityTypeConfiguration<T Entity>` Mapping Classes. Set all of your `ToTable()` methods to begin with your plugin name as follows:

```
ToTable("PluginName_InterestingStuff");

HasKey(k => k.Id);
Property(p => p.Puppies);
...
```

This way, the `Install()` method in the `ObjectContext` class will generate SQL tables starting with your plugin name:

```
dbo.PluginName_Foo
dbo.PluginName_Bar
```

If you configured your code-first classes correctly, you will probably have some foreign keys. By design, these will also follow the naming convention, and their names will start with your Plugin name.

Leverage this by creating a Stored Procedure in your application database that will drop all foreign keys and tables containing `@YourPluginName`. Below is SQL script that will do just that.

```
/** 
    This is a convenience proc to uninstall a nop commerce plugin "dynamically"
    This proc DROPs all foreign keys, and then all tables, 
    whose name contains the @YourPluginName param.
    If naming conventions are followed, 
    there will be no side effects, but USE WITH CAUTION! 

    Please do a SELECT on sys.tables 
    with your Param before running this. 
**/

CREATE PROC sp_UninstallPluginTables
(
    @YourPluginName VARCHAR(250) /*This will typically be the nopcommerce plugin name */
)
/*----------------------------------FOREIGN KEYS---------------------------------------*/
declare CollectFkNames cursor for
  SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + T.NAME + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + FK.NAME
  FROM sys.foreign_keys FK
    INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON T.object_id = FK.parent_object_id
  WHERE FK.NAME LIKE @YourPluginName + '_%'
  ORDER BY T.Name DESC

declare @DropForeignKeysCmd varchar(max)

open CollectFkNames
    fetch next from CollectFkNames 
      into @DropForeignKeysCmd
    while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin
      exec(@DropForeignKeysCmd)
      fetch next from CollectFkNames 
      into @DropForeignKeysCmd
    end
close CollectFkNames
deallocate CollectFkNames
GO

/*-------------------------------------TABLES------------------------------------------*/
declare CollectTableNames cursor for
  SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + T.NAME
  FROM sys.tables T 
  WHERE T.NAME LIKE @YourPluginName + '_%'
  ORDER BY T.Name DESC

declare @DropTablesCmd varchar(max)

open CollectTableNames
    fetch next from CollectTableNames 
      into @DropTablesCmd
    while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin
      exec(@DropTablesCmd)
      fetch next from CollectTableNames 
      into @DropTablesCmd
    end
close CollectTableNames
deallocate CollectTableNames
GO
```